# Most efficient way to populate a page through specified time intervals?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'll get straight to it.

layout.html

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td><div id="corner1"></div><div id="c11"></div><div id="c12"></div></td>
  <td><div id="corner2"></div><div id="c21"></div><div id="c22"></div></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><div id="corner3"></div><div id="c31"></div><div id="c32"></div></td>
  <td><div id="corner4"></div><div id="c41"></div><div id="c42"></div></td>
 </tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" value="12" name="tableid" />
```

main.js

```
populateID = setInterval(Populate, 1000);
function Populate() {
 $.ajax({
  url: 'jquery/populate.php',
  data: 'tableid=' + $("#tableid").val(),
  success: function(data) {
   fillem(data);
  }
 });
}

function fillem(data) {
 if(data.c1) {
  $("#c11").html(data.c1);
  $("#c12").html(data.filler);
 }else{
  $("#c11").html(data.filler);
 }
 if(data.c2) {
  $("#c21").html(data.c2);
  $("#c22").html(data.filler);
 }else{
  $("#c21").html(data.filler);
 }
 if(data.c3) {
  $("#c31").html(data.c3);
  $("#c32").html(data.filler);
 }else{
  $("#c31").html(data.filler);
 }
 if(data.c4) {
  $("#c41").html(data.c4);
  $("#c42").html(data.filler);
 }else{
  $("#c41").html(data.filler);
 }

 if(data.timer) {
  $("#timer").html(data.timer);
 }else{
  $("#timer").html("");
 }

 if(data.corner) {
  $("#corner" + data.corner).html("ACTIVE");
 }
}
```

I'm pretty sure this could be done in a more efficient way, I don't care if it involves changing the DOM structure.

For example, It does sound bad to always have 4 "corner" divs when no two of them will be used simultaneously.  And since the ajax response will change upon every request, sometimes a div "flashes" quickly when being populated with new data, which is also annoying.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: define "efficient".  Faster? Less CPU intensive? Less code?

Comment: Less code, better document structure (i.e. no unnecessary output or empty divs .. etc.) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert your `data.c#` to arrays, so it's `data.c[1]`, and then you use a simple `for()` loop to do only a SINGLE output block.

```
for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
   if(data.c[i]) {
       $('#c' + i + '1').html(data.c[i]);
       $('#c' + i + '2').html(data.filler);
   }
}
```

Comment: I followed this procedure throughout the whole script, and with some more JQuery research I managed to cut the script (and output) size in half, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Below is some minor modification. Try and let me know,

**Note:** `data['c'+i]` will evaluate to something that is same as data.c1, data.c2, data.c3 and data.c4

```
function fillem(data) {
   for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
       if (data['c'+i]){
          $('#c'+i+'1').html(data['c'+i]);
          $('#c'+i+'2').html(data['filler']);
       } else {
          $('#c'+i+'1').html(data['filler']);
       }
   }

 if(data.timer) {
  $("#timer").html(data.timer);
 }else{
  $("#timer").html("");
 }

 if(data.corner) {
  $("#corner" + data.corner).html("ACTIVE");
 }
}
```